# CakePHP - Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'title'

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

My add.ctp form is returning "Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'title' doesn't have a default value". And I don't know why, everything seems to be written correctly. I enter the title but it doesn't save it to the database.

**AlbumsController.php**

```
class AlbumsController extends AppController {        
    public function add() {            
        if($this->request->is('post')) {                
            $this->Album->create();
            $this->Album->save('$this->request->data');                
        }            
    }        
}
```

**add.ctp**

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Album', array('type' => 'file'));
echo "<br>";
echo $this->Form->input('created', array('label' => '', 'separator' => ' ', 'timeFormat' => '24'));
echo "<br>";
echo $this->Form->input('title', array('label' => 'Naslov albuma<br>'));
echo "<br><br>";
echo $this->Form->end('Create album');
?>
```

**MySQL**
[image: structure]
[image: table]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to change this line :

```
$this->Album->save('$this->request->data');
```

and remove the single quotes , you don't need it :

```
$this->Album->save($this->request->data);
```

---

however -*and as a side note*- , to set a default NULL value to your title field from your mysql you may update your table structure as follows to make title field accepts null values:

```
ALTER TABLE `tableName` CHANGE `title` `title` varchar(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

Comment: yeah I don't need it null, I need the title. Thanks mate